# Move tkinter canvas left-upper corner to the item

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an object on the canvas and I want to scale it. When I scale it (+) it moves down-right side, but I want canvas to move with this moving-scaling item (catch item in the user view and it will be an anchor). How could I do that? I need this because if I would have large canvas items will jump on the very far distances and it will be tricky to find them after scaling. I save all items in the dictionary if it helps

PS. Use + - to scale

```
from tkinter import *

main = Tk()
canvas_items = {}

frame = Frame(main)
frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
canvas = Canvas(frame, bg='bisque')

# Create new item on the canvas
new_item = canvas.create_line(60, 60, 90, 90, activefill='purple')

# Add it to dict with all items
canvas_items[new_item] = [60, 60, 90, 90]

# for scale
plus_multiply_k = 1.02
minus_multiply_k = 0.98

# All functions
def scroll_start(event):
    canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)

def scroll_move(event):
    canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)

def scale_plus(event):
    canvas.scale("all", 0, 0, plus_multiply_k, plus_multiply_k)

def scale_minus(event):
    canvas.scale("all", 0,0,minus_multiply_k,minus_multiply_k)


def get_coords(event):
    x = int(canvas.canvasx(event.x))
    y = int(canvas.canvasy(event.y))
    print(f'{x} . {y}')

# All binds

main.bind('<Key-plus>', scale_plus)
main.bind('<Key-minus>', scale_minus)

canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", scroll_start)
canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-3>", get_coords)
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", scroll_move)

# Mainloop
canvas.pack(anchor='nw', expand=True, fill=BOTH)
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: ***"I want canvas to move with ... catch item ... be an anchor"***: This is contradict, if you move the canvas the item move also. I guess you want the item to stay at the same `coords`?

Comment: @stovfl yes, sth like in the google maps when I scale a map

Comment: ***"like in the google maps"***: There the map, here your `Canvas`, are scaled also. Read about the arguments `xoffset, yoffset` using [Canvas.scale-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.scale-method) this allows to correct the coords of the scaled items.